Why are sequences and series typically taught in Calculus 2 and not Calculus 1?
As a current math student, I find the inclusion of sequences and series in Calculus 2 rather odd. Calculus 2 is a course dedicated to integration and its applications (integration techniques, accumulation functions, position from velocity, probability density distributions, work, arc length, and an introduction to differential equations). However, the inclusion of sequences and series at the very end of Calculus 2 seems rather odd, especially given that this topic has more overlap with differential calculus (the main focus of Calculus 1) than with integral calculus (the main focus of Calculus 2).
In a unit on sequences and series in a typical Calculus 2 course (or Unit 10 of AP Calculus BC, which covers sequences and series), one would typically cover convergence tests and Taylor Series. Most of the convergence tests (such as the ratio test) require, at most, differential calculus to sort out edge cases (such as the ratio of consecutive terms approaching 1). There is an integral test, but integration is usually introduced at the end of Calculus 1, so someone who completed a Calculus 1 course would still probably be able to understand the integral test. Taylor Series are built through repeated differentiation; someone who completed a Calculus 1 course would still probably be able to understand and construct a Taylor Series. Linearization is already taught in Calculus 1, and I see no reason why a Calculus 1 student would not understand fitting a polynomial to an analytic function if they could understand fitting a line to a differentiable function.
Given all of this, it makes more sense to include sequences and series in Calculus 1 than to include it in Calculus 2.

To fit sequences and series in Calculus 1, you'd need to remove something else. So you'd need to argue that sequences and series make MORE sense in Calculus 1 than something in the current standard list of topics.

Also, can't do the "integral test" for convergence of infinite sums without knowing about integrals...

In the past, I have motivated sequences and series (immediately following a unit on integration techniques) by asking what is the antiderivative of sin(x^2). This ties it in to calculus 2 and leads into a discussion of non-elementary functions that would be difficult to motivate in calculus 1

For your consideration, I'm starting (infinite) sequences and series next week in my (HS) calculus classes, and we'll start up integration in the new (calendar) year. Poke me in chat if you want to hear more =)

First-semester calculus is a service course. For example, in the US these days, there will typically be a physics course for engineering majors that has first-semester calculus as a prerequisite, and also a physics course for students in the life sciences that has it as a corequisite.
The people in other departments who teach those courses want their students to be able to do certain basic things using calculus, and they want them to be able to do that by a certain point in time. For that reason, the first-semester calculus course includes all the most important and fundamental topics in integration and differentiation. Everything that didn't fit goes in second-semester calculus.

Regarding your first paragraph, calculus has been mostly a service course in the U.S. since probably before 1900. For what it's worth, I'm not sure when "different flavors" of calculus arose (not mentioned anywhere here thus far, probably because "Calculus 1" and "Calculus 2" tend to refer specifically to the more mathy flavor taken by math and physical science majors), such as calculus for business majors and calculus for life science majors, but these other flavors of calculus have been offered in many U.S. colleges/universities since at least the early 1970s.

This is apparently U.S. based. For those not familiar with U.S. Calculus 1, the following list of Calculus 1 topics at Boston University is typical of what is covered in a 1-semester U.S. Calculus 1 course:

Review of Pre-Calculus topics (a day or two)
Limits and Continuity: limit laws, continuous functions, limits involving infinity
Tangent lines and rates of change
Derivative and its meaning
Differentiation Rules: Linearity, Product rule, Quotient rule, Chain rule
Other examples of derivatives: trigonometric functions, inverse functions, implicit derivatives, logarithmic differentiation
Applications of differentiation: related rates, max/min problems, derivatives and shapes of curves
Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, techniques of integration: “u”–substitution method

My experience in TA'ing and teaching Calculus 1 (1 high school, 6 colleges/universities) is that it's a struggle to finish with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (pseudo-rigorous proof) followed by a 1 to 3 lecture introduction to simple integration-by-substitution evaluations. There's no way at all to cover sequences and series, at least not with the students and their backgrounds I had.
Regarding "Linearization is already taught in Calculus 1, and I see no reason why a Calculus 1 student would not understand fitting a polynomial to an analytic function if they could understand fitting a line to a differentiable function, I nearly always included a discussion of quadratic approximations in Calculus 1 as a preview of what they'll see with Taylor series in Calculus 2.
In this Mathematics Stack Exchange (MSE) answer I give a lengthy discussion of something I did regarding linear and quadratic approximations, beginning in 2000. Before then I had not been aware of how graphing calculators could be used in the way I describe in that MSE answer, something I learned from someone's post in the AP-Calculus discussion group at Math Forum (no longer exists, even the archived posts, except a few random ones at the Internet Archive). In fact, when I first saw the idea in that AP-Calculus post in Fall 2000 (only briefly described, and nowhere near as nuanced and detailed as I describe in my MSE answer), I happened to be teaching both Calculus 1 and Calculus 2 classes. The mathematics department desired that I incorporate/use Mathematica from time to time (students sat in lab-science-like benches with computers having Mathematica on the "lab tables"), so in class that Fall we did the kind of graphing explorations I describe in my MSE answer.

This is US centric. In Romania (Soviet system, more or less) we learn calculus in 11th grade (16 to 17 years old, high school) and 12th grade (17 to 18 years old, last year of high school).
Sequences and series are taught first, in 11th grade, as a prerequisite for limits of functions.

FYI, calculus is taught in most U.S. high schools and 15%-20% of students reach this level while in high school. But I suspect the majority of these students who actually have to take calculus in college (a large majority overall don't, of course) wind up taking Calculus 1 in college due to not learning the material very well in high school. Incidentally, I believe about 15% of U.S. college students take any calculus -- $0.7$ million each year among $18$ million students (the latter includes all $4$ years)

gives $\frac{0.7 \times 4}{18}.$ Regarding the reference to AP Calculus, this is a specific type of U.S. high school course with a comprehensive standardized exam at the end that most U.S. colleges award college credit for when successfully completed -- Calculus 1 credit for AP Calculus AB and Calculus 1 & 2 for AP Calculus BC, the latter not offered at many of the smaller or more rural high schools and also taken by a much more select group of students than the former.

In Romania, is calculus taught to all students in high school, or just to the better students?


I see no reason why a Calculus 1 student would not understand fitting a polynomial to an analytic function if they could understand fitting a line to a differentiable function.

Of course the syllabus could be organized in that way or in many other ways, but as Serge Lang liked to say, the syllabus ultimately does have to be ordered in a definite way along the time axis, so in the US we are stuck with sequences and series taught later on, which is reinforced because that's the way the textbooks continue to be written.
The book that largely codified (calcified?) the way calculus is taught in the US since the second half of the 20th century is Thomas' Calculus and Analytic Geometry, and the YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNqkR9UYhj4 compares the 3rd edition in 1960 with a more recent edition. The main thing you'll like is that the video presents the table of contents in the 3rd edition: watch 2:13-3:20. In particular, Thomas in 1960 didn't present series until after multivariable derivatives and integrals.  You complain about series appearing at the end of single-variable calculus and now you see that it was once presented after multivariable calculus: progress!
I am looking now at a copy of Calculus by Lipman Bers from the late 1960s and his order of material will look familiar to you: functions, limits, derivatives, integrals, and then series (and then multivariable calculus topics).  So the order of material has been largely static for the past 50 years.  Series have remained whether they are in US textbooks probably to get through the basic material about derivatives and integrals first.

I get the connection you are making, but it's not a key as for, e.g. another method of integration with other methods of integration.  But series (in context of first year differentiation/integration) is more of a "special topic".  As such it makes sense at the end of a standard year of calculus.  Essentially, it's lower priority.  Certainly, it's not important for a standard calc-based physics course.  If anything, the topic is sort of priming the pump for use later in more detailed manners in an analysis course (that most students will never have).  It's really a side topic.
Note also that Granville (the stereotypical US calculus text from 1900-1960) has series after the end of single variable integration and before an intro to ODEs.  (Very much the standard order we still see now!)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GcNm3vXQpY
Finally, I would beware of trying too much to make the calculus course a logical set of dependencies.  It's normal for some amount of recursion.  And for tradeoffs on what to cover (there is no one perfect order).  Also, order for pedagogy is not the same as order for a review type reconstruction.  [We routinely get the people here asking to change the order to have real analysis before/with engineering calculus.]
P.s.  For the Rumanian:  series are really treated several times and in different ways in the US curriculum.  In (strong/honors/college-prep) second year algebra (age 16 or so, pre calculus), series notation and important example series (and proof by induction) are covered.  Then convergence tests after calc 1/2 (which really you need, to do some of the tests).  Then as solutions for DEs (within a diffyQs course).
